# How to place abstract text in front of abstract key?

Tags: abstract

I want to place my abstract text behind the abstract-key(which is used in all article), and left-aligned rather than centered on the page. How do I do this in LaTeX?

I want the following format:

```
Abstract: some text is here.
```

The default abstract format (which I want to change it) is:

```
                           Abstract

Some text is here
```

Comment: What do you mean by “abstract-key”? If you mean the *text “Abstract”*,  then surely you want to put your abstract *behind* the abstract key, rather than in front of it.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example how you could redefine the `abstract` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \noindent\bfseries\abstractname:\normalfont}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  some text is here.
\end{abstract}
\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

You could also customize the end code of the new `abstract` for making a paragraph break etc. However, I guess a `\section` would follow, so it would be ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`abstract`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/abstract) package to customise the abstract block as you want it by using the `runin` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[runin]{abstract}
\setlength{\abstitleskip}{-\parindent}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```